# WPF Application base class?

Tags: wpf, inheritance

I'm not even sure if this is even possible, but I've just started WPF development on a few new projects and tried to wrap up some common functionality by creating a mini-framework. Just things like exception handling and thread management.

What I would like to do is replace this line...

`public partial class App : Application`

with

`public partial class App : MyFrameworkApplication`

I've got the libraries set up and referenced, but I get an error regarding the 'partially' declared `App` class, presumably because it's still referencing the old base class.

Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT: @Jeff M: No, your solution didn't work. I suspect because the `MyFrameworkApplication` is actually in a library and the `z` namespace declaration fails to recognise the library's namespace. I've got it referenced in the App.xaml.cs, but the suspicious looking error is:

`Error  3   Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'MyLibraryNamespace' that is not included in the assembly.`

I can circumvent the problem by creating a proxy class within the local namespace and having it derive from the library class...but it's a bit smelly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect it's because the the underlying XAML root is still an `Application` as opposed to `MyFrameworkApplication`.  I'd guess the generated baml uses the root as it's parent class.  Try changing it to the appropriate names.

e.g.,

```
<z:MyFrameworkApplication x:Class="MyNamespace.App"
             ...
             xmlns:z="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">
    ...
</z:MyFrameworkApplication>
```

It seems my suspicions were correct.

From the docs in [Code-Behind and XAML in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970568.aspx#Code_behind__Event_Handler__and_Partial_Class):

> ### Code-behind, Event Handler, and Partial Class Requirements in WPF
>
> - ***The partial class must derive from the type that backs the root element.*** (emphasis mine)
> - Note that under the default behavior of the markup compile build actions, you can leave the derivation blank in the partial class
>   definition on the code-behind side. The compiled result will assume
>   the page root's backing type to be the basis for the partial class,
>   even if it not specified. However, relying on this behavior is not a
>   best practice.
> - The event handlers you write in the code behind must be instance methods and cannot be static methods. These methods must be defined by
>   the partial class within the CLR namespace identified by **x:Class**. You
>   cannot qualify the name of an event handler to instruct a XAML
>   processor to look for an event handler for event wiring in a different
>   class scope.
> - The handler must match the delegate for the appropriate event in the backing type system.
> - For the Microsoft Visual Basic language specifically, you can use the language-specific **Handles** keyword to associate handlers with
>   instances and events in the handler declaration, instead of attaching
>   handlers with attributes in XAML. However, this technique does have
>   some limitations because the **Handles** keyword cannot support all of the
>   specific features of the WPF event system, such as certain routed
>   event scenarios or attached events. For details, see [Visual Basic and WPF Event Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970684.aspx).

The root application type in code-behind and in the xaml must agree.

Comment: Finally got it! The CLR string I needed was: `xmlns:x="clr-namespace:MyLibraryNamespace;assembly=MyLibraryNamespace"`